# searching for multiple columns in a dataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have this code for searching for a specific column name or column number in a datagridview:

```
        string str = kartSearchTxt.Text;
        string value = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                if (value.Contains(str) == false)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
                    i--;
                }  
        }
    }
```

I've tried different solutions like having "2 for loops " for searching through columns aswell, but it didn't work.

how can I search through multiple columns?

Comment: 2 loops should do. Paste your code with 2 loops and what didn't work with it

Comment: hi i used this for the columns that contained my search : for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 2; j < 12; j++)
                {
                    value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                    if (value.Contains(str) == false)
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
                        i--;
                    }
                }
            }

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop like this

```
for (int i = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
    {
        if (!column.Visible || column.DisplayIndex < 0)
            continue;
        value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[column.DisplayIndex].Value.ToString();
        if (value.Contains(str) == false)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Because when you remove row(s) from grid, `dataGridView1.Rows` takes new value

Comment: but what should i use in the "Cells[] " property ?

Comment: it gives me this error : "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index"

Comment: Which line throws exception?

Comment: this line : "value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[column.DisplayIndex].Value.ToString();"

Comment: Please try last edit, I hope this will solve your problem

Comment: thank you for answering again , but i got the same error at the same line